# How to solve HTTP error 429 "too many requests"

Tags: r, web-scraping, timedelay, http-status-code-429

i tried the following code but after some scrapes shows the following error HTTP 429 aka too many requests. Is there any kind of delaying the algorith in order to make the job done? Note the code runs for a single page.and all the functions i created are running correctly

```
    CARS<-data.frame()
for (page_result in seq(from=1, to=2)) {
  link<-paste0("https://www.car.gr/classifieds/cars/?condition=used&modified=15&offer_type=sale&pg=",
               page_result,"&registration-from=2000&significant_damage=f")
  page<-curl::curl(link) %>% read_html(link)
  
  page<-read_html(link)
  
  Title<-page %>% html_nodes(".title") %>% html_text2()
  
  Price<-page %>% html_nodes(".price-fmt") %>% html_text2()
  
  car_links<-page %>% html_nodes(".row-anchor") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>% paste0("https://www.car.gr", .)
  
  color<-sapply(car_links,get_color)
  gearing_system<-sapply(car_links,get_gearing_sys)
  HP<-sapply(car_links,get_car_HP)
  CC<-sapply(car_links,get_car_CC)
  FUEL<-sapply(car_links,get_car_fuel)
  KM<-sapply(car_links,get_car_km)
  DATE<-sapply(car_links,get_car_km)
  CATEGORY<-sapply(car_links,get_car_category)  
  CARS <- rbind(CARS,Title,Price,color,gearing_system,HP,CC,FUEL,KM,DATE)
  
  print("Page",page_result,"of","2")
}
```

Comment: The error explains what's wrong. You made too many requests too fast, so the site blocked you. Classified ad sites *hate* screen scrapers because they're forced to pay quite a lot to server data without any benefit. The site may have returned how long to wait before retrying in the `Response-After` header

Comment: Try putting a suitable `Sys.sleep()` line in your loop. I like things like `Sys.sleep(sample(1:5, 1))` which also stops it looking like a regular request, and then just let it run slowly while you do something else.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i tried paths_allowed command via robotstxt package and the result was true. So i thought to make tha code more slow in order to avoid it.

Comment: @AndrewGustar yeah i will try something like that.

Comment: The *site* blocked you. Not your code. No matter what you do on the client side, if they don't like you they'll block you. The only thing you can do is add a delay and respect the `Retry-After` code

Comment: Once they have blocked your IP address you might have to wait some time (maybe 24 hours???) before they will let you have another go.

Comment: FYI, "paths allowed" says that robots can scrape it, I don't assume it makes any implication of query frequency. Slow your query, don't anger the server admins.